# How to convert from double for values larger than long in java

Tags: java, double, long-integer

I am facing issues while converting from double to long:

```
double power = Math.pow(2, 63);
long powerInLong = (double) power;
```

The above code returns:

```
9223372036854775807
```

while it should return:

```
-9223372036854775808
```

I am confused why is this happening.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a conversion from `double` to `long`, which is a narrowing primitive conversion.

This conversion is clearly specified in the [JLS §5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (emphasis mine):

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type
>   T takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int,
>      as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
>    - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward
>        zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are
>        two cases:
>
>      a. If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long, then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>
>      b. Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of the first step is the int value V.
>    - **Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true**:
>
>      a. The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or negative infinity), and the result of the first step is
>        the smallest representable value of type int or long.
>
>      b. The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), **and the result of the first step is
>        the largest representable value of type int or long.**

Because 2^63 exceeds the range of `long` (but not the range of double), converting it to a long will result in the largest `long`. This can be demonstrated also by converting `Math.pow(2, 64)` to `long`, which results in the same `long`.

Comment: Just to add: BigInteger may be able to hold such value.